# Extracting polygons touched by lines using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, extract, hexagonal-grid

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

I made an hexagonal grid layer and also I have a road layer (lines). The end goal is to calculate every hexagon's distance to particular variables (sport facilities, commercial places, important squares, trees, etc) and ponderate them to get a "problematic" index. The closer to those variables, the more problematic the area in the hexagon will be considered. Then, via an Spatial Join (unless I find a better tool), that index will be transferred to the line layer where every segment will get as a value being the mean of the index in the hexagons it touches/crosses.

[image]

The thing is, the grid has 200 square meter hexagons that add up to 481338 polygons, and the road layer has (for now, most likely to be reduced) about 7600 segments. My PC isn't very powerful so I would like to reduce the number of elements to be processed, especially since many of the hexagons will be worthless as they are not touched by any road, and work with only those polygons that I know will be able to transfer their index to the road layer.

I already achieved that using Select by Location with intersect, but I would like to find a tool that, with the right parameters, does this without the need of manual intervention. I have intention of creating a model so that this process can be executed in further analysis without having to do extra work, just entering the initial layers and clicking Run. Also I don't want to increment the hexagon's area to reduce their number (I might even reduce the area to have more hexagons).

I also thought that there might be a parameter in the Generate tessellation tool, or another different tool, that creates a grid consisting only of polygons along a line, those being the roads. Still haven't found this yet.

I should add that I'd like to be the grid to be hexagonal, as i consider its shape to be better for this particular task. I know Grid Index Features tool creates the grid I want, but it only creates squares.

The thing is, I know how to select the overlapping features and then copy them to another feature/layer with a process consisting of various steps, I even found a new tool to add to the toolbox that lets me create the exact thing I need. I already got exactly what I wanted, but I still have the doubt if there is a way within, lets call it "vanilla", ArcGIS to do this exact same thing with just one step, one single tool that you input your roads and creates these hexagons along them. Without having to add new tools or needing more than 1 step and manual intervention.

Does this tool exist?

Something you can show to a person who barely knows ArcGIS and say "you execute this, this happens, period".

Comment: How is your data stored? If they are shapefiles, adding spatial indices can significantly improve performance of spatial selection tools.

Comment: Both are in a geodatabase. Nevertheless, i'd also like to know the solution to my question in particular (first, out of curiosity) because i know my way around GIS, but my other coworkers don't and i'd like to get a process as simple as possible. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: I don't see a question here. You already know how to select overlapping features. What is the issue? Do you need help copying them to a new feature class?

Comment: I've updated my post with one last paragraph summarizing all of it and stating exacty what I'm looking for, as it seems I was not clear enough just writing my doubts.

Comment: Have you considered modelbuilder? If you have found tools that do the job you could string them together in a model and expose that as a single tool for distribution.